# Filter list of entity objects by string child object property using Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to return an IQueryable lands filtered by a child object property Owner.Name. Is working well with the query style solution, but I want to use a lambda one.

On short these are my classes mapped by EntityFramework:

```
public class Land
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int LandId { get; set; }

        public virtual Land Lands { get; set; }
}
```

The query which is working fine:

```
 var list = from land in db.Lands
                   join owner in db.Owners on land.Id equals Owner.LandId
                   where owner.Name.Contains("Smit")
                   select land;
```

I was trying using this:

```
var list = db.Lands.Where(lnd => lnd.Owners.Count() > 0 &&
             lnd.Owners.Where(own => own.Name.Contains("Smit")).Count() > 0);
```

It works only for small lists, but for some with thousands of records it gives timeout.

Comment: Where did the property `owner.Name` came from ?

Comment: It would be better to rearrange the data to a data structure like Lookup, which would make your querying many time faster, your current query has the time complexity of O(N^2), which is killing performance for lots of data, and for 1000 records complexity becomes 1 million iterations

Comment: In actual Query version, you are using a Join, then why would you not Join in the Lambda query, it is bound to have an impact

Answer (score 2):

Well, one issue which may be causing the speed problem is that your lambda version and your non-lambda versions do very different things. You're non lambda is doing a join with a where on one side of the join.

Why not just write the lambda equivalent of it?

```
var list = db.Lands.Join(db.Owners.Where(x=> x.Name.Contains("Smit")), a=> a.Id, b => b.LandId, (a,b) => a).toList();
```

I mean, that is the more direct equivalent of your non lambda

Comment: This is the correct replacement of the OP's query version

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one:

```
var list = db.Lands.Where(lnd => lnd.Owners.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("Smit")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more straightforward:

```
var lands = db.Owners.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Smit")).Select(o => o.Lands);
```

You just need to make sure that Owner.Name is not null and LINQ will do the rest.

Comment: You re forgetting join by LandId

Comment: That relation should be taken care of by Entity Framework itself. The relationship can be defined using convention, like in the example above, or explicit using Fluent API.